# Why can't SseEmitter send data to the front in real time

Tags: java, spring-boot

For sending data to the front in real time, I use SseEmitter to implement it. The server code is as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sse")
public class TestSSE {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestSSE.class);
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mvcTaskExecutor")
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor mvcTaskExecutor;
    @GetMapping("")
    public SseEmitter sseDemo(HttpServletRequest request) throws InterruptedException {
        final SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(0L); //timeout设置为0表示不超时
        mvcTaskExecutor.execute(() -> {
            try {
                for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
                    emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().data("hello"+i));
                    Thread.sleep(1000*1);
                }
                emitter.complete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                emitter.completeWithError(e);
            }
        });
        System.out.println("run immediately");
        return emitter;
    }
}
```

The information is sent to the front only after “emitter.complete();” is executed. Can you tell me why? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are using spring mvc. This is not possible because the http thread launched by spring mvc is not the mvcTaskExecutor object but another thread that spring mvc launches is down by the embedded tomcat.
As a solution I suggest you use a socket or if the project is not in maintenance to migrate from spring mvc to spring webflux and instead of returning an SseEmitter to return a Flux.

Comment: Thank you. I directly access the service in Google browser, the program runs normally. When access it in my Vue program，it didn't. Let me sort out my program again.